# Solve the linear congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve the pair $x \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$ and $10x \equiv 6 \pmod{28}$.

So this means, $10x \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$ and $10x \equiv 6 \pmod{28}$.

So this has a unique solution $10x \equiv a \pmod{252}$

So we have $5 + 9k = 6 + 28n \implies  9k - 28n = 1$

And then I would solve that equation and then back substitute.

But my question, is there an easier solution?

Comment: k=-3, n=-1. Then a=-22

Comment: Cancel $2$ to get the equivalent $\,5x\equiv 3\pmod{14}.\,$  Now you can use CRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations can be put as

$$\begin{cases}x=5\pmod 9\\{}\\5x=3\pmod{14}\end{cases}$$

But $\;5^{-1}=3\pmod{14}\;$ since $\;5\cdot3=15=1\pmod{14}\;$, so the second equation ca be written as $\;x=9\pmod{14}\;$ , so $\;x=23\;$ is already a solution.

Comment: The question asks for all solutions, not just one. All solutions are given by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). One would find that $x\equiv 23\pmod{9\cdot 14}$ gives all the solutions.

Comment: The question at the end of the OP's post asks whether there is "an easier solution". That's what I addressed.

Comment: The problem (mentioned at the beginning) asks for all the solutions (that's what solving an equation/congruence/etc. normally means). The OP uses one method as a solution for finding all solutions $x$ and wants an easier method. The "solution" that the OP mentions is "a method of solving this problem", not "an $x$ that satisfies the equation".

Comment: @user236182 Your opinion, not mine nor the OP's as he accepted this answer. It seems to be that, as I gathered, he already knew, more or less, how to reach a general solution and he was more worried about a simpler, or the simplest, one, whatever that may mean. Nevertheless, from the general set up of my answer, also the most general solution can be reached pretty easily.

Comment: I didn't downvote, by the way. Someone else did and upvoted my comments. I still stand by my reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

A start: Reduce to a more standard Chinese Remainder Theorem problem, by rewriting the second congruence as $5x\equiv 3\pmod{14}$. Multiplying by $3$ we get the equivalent congruence $x\equiv 9\pmod{14}$.

Note that there will be a unique solution modulo $126$, but two solutions modulo $252$.

Answer (score 0):

the first equation can be written as $$x=5+9m, m\in \mathbb{Z}$$ and the second one as $$10x=6+28n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ thus we have  the equation $$44=28n-90m$$ slving this we get $$m=2+14k,n=8+45k$$ plugging this in the equations above  we get $$x=23+126k$$ as the searched solutions.